# How many of subgroups of order $2$ are there in $S_4$?

Tags: group-theory

Any subgroup of order $2$ will be cyclic subgroup and so will be generated by single element of order $2$ in $S_4$, so to count number of subgroups of order $2$ we need to count number of elements of order $2$ in $S_4$, I tried counting them but I got answer $8$ but is $9$ actually.

Comment: Six transpositions + three products of two disjoint transpositions.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $\sigma\in S_4$ has order two. Then $\sigma$ changes some element $x$. Let $y=\sigma(x)$. Then $\sigma(y)=x$.

This shows that $\sigma$ is the product of some disjoint $2$-cycles.

The possibilities are:
$$(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4),(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4)(2,3)$$

Answer (score 1):

Your starting point sounds good; we only need to consider elements of order 2. If we consider a sequence of four numbers, these elements can be thought of as the "swapping" permutations.

There are $ {4 \choose 2} = 6$ ways to choose a pair of numbers which swap and leave the other values alone. Then for each of these, we can also consider swapping the remaining two values. This gives another 6/2=3 (dividing by two to prevent double counting) permutations of order 2. Giving a total of 9.

Answer (score 0):

The permutations (elements) of order two in $S_4$ are the following:

$$\underbrace{(12), (13), (14), (23), (2 4), (34)}_{6 \;\;\text{two-cycles}}, \underbrace{(12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)}_{3\;\; \text{products of disjoint two-cycles.}}$$

As Fransesco mentions in a comment above: We see  "six transpositions + three products of two disjoint transpositions."

Comment: Why giving an answer identical to the other one?

Comment: I was writing this post while the other posted his/hers, which I saw only ofter submitting it. @FrancescoPolizzi